# Динамическое меню в Битриксе

Tags: битрикс, 1с, меню

Всем привет!

Решаю задачу, казалось бы, простую: добавление к статическому меню динамического меню из инфоблока. Статика загружается в меню **.left.menu.php** в корню Битрикса, динамическое меню грузится в **.left.menu_ext.php** также в корню.

При слиянии массива для меню получается такая структура:

```
   Array
(
    [4957] => Array
        (
            [0] => Раздел1
            [1] => /service/4957
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [4958] => Array
        (
            [0] => Раздел2
            [1] => /service/4958
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                )

        )
...

[1546061] => Array
        (
            [0] => Пункт1
            [1] => /service/punkt1/
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [FROM_IBLOCK] => 1
                    [IS_PARENT] => 4957
                    [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
                )

        )

    [1546062] => Array
        (
            [0] => Пункт2
            [1] => /service/punkt2/
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [FROM_IBLOCK] => 1
                    [IS_PARENT] => 4957
                    [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2
                )

        )
```

Корневый разделы не имеют родителей. Элементы второго уровня имеют атрибуты:  [IS_PARENT] => код и  [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 2

В итоге почему разделы выстраюиваются на одном уровне, а элементы второго уровня, вкладываются один в другой, и походы на лестницу, где каждый шаг ведет на новый уровень, явно не 2.

Визуально это получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо того, чтобы представлять в виде:

```
> Раздел -> Пункт 1
>           Пункт 2
>           Пункт 3 ...
> 
> Раздел 2 -> Р2Пункт1
>             Р2Пункт2
>             ...
```

Кто решал подобные задачи? Что не так со структурой массива?

Как правильно перестроить структуру массива, чтобы были вложения в разделах, в виде подвложений.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die(); // проверяем, загружена ли служебная часть сайта (ядро)?>
<?
/*
Структура массива $arResult
Массив $arResult состоит из вложенных массивов, соответсвующих пунктам меню.
Порядок следования пунктов
Вложенные массивы содержат ключи:
TEXT - текст текущего пункта меню 
LINK - ссылка текущего пункта меню 
SELECTED - выбран ли пункт меню в данный момент 
PERMISSION - доступ на страницу указанную в $LINK, возможны следующие значения: 
 D - доступ запрещён 
 R - чтение (право просмотра содержимого файла) 
 U - документооборот (право на редактирование файла в режиме документооборота) 
 W - запись (право на прямое редактирование) 
 X - полный доступ (право на прямое редактирование файла и право на изменение прав доступа на данных файл) 
ADDITIONAL_LINKS - дополнительные ссылки для подсветки меню 
ITEM_TYPE - "D" - директория (если LINK заканчивается на "/"), иначе "P" - страница 
ITEM_INDEX - порядковый номер пункта меню 
PARAMS - параметры пунктов меню
DEPTH_LEVEL - уровень вложенности пункта меню (1 для главного, 2 и далее для вложенных)
IS_PARENT - флаг того, что у этого пункта меню будет подменю

Вывод производится вложенными списками вида
<ul id="horizontal-multilevel-menu">
 <li><a>Пункт первого уровня вложенности</a></li>
 <li><a>Пункт первого уровня вложенности</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a>Пункт второго уровня вложенности</a></li>
   <li><a>Пункт второго уровня вложенности</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a>Пункт первого уровня вложенности</a></li>
</ul>
*/
?>
<?if (!empty($arResult)): // если есть хотя бы 1 пункт меню, можно начинать вывод?>
<ul id="horizontal-multilevel-menu">

<?
$previousLevel = 0; // переменная содержит значение DEPTH_LEVEL предыдущего пункта
foreach($arResult as $arItem): // пробегаем по пунктам, $arItem - массив с информацией о текущем пункте?>

 <?if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
 <?// если уровень вложенности текущего пункта меню меньше чем у предыдущего, значит "подменю" закончилось и нужно закрыть список?>
  <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]));?>
 <?endif?>

 <?if ($arItem["IS_PARENT"]): //если пункт содержит подменю, выводим ссылку и начинаем новый список (тег <ul>)?>

  <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1): // если уровень вложенности =1, т.е. это главное меню?>
   <?// выводим ссылку и добавляем класс "root-item" если пункт неактивный и "root-item-selected" если активный?>
   <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>root-item-selected<?else:?>root-item<?endif?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
    <ul>
  <?else: // для остальных уровней вложенности?>
   <?// выводим ссылку и добавляем класс "parent". Если пункт активный, для элемента списка <li> добавляем класс "item-selected"?>
   <li<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?> class="item-selected"<?endif?>><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="parent"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
    <ul>
  <?endif?>

 <?else: // для пунктов, не содержащих подменю?>

  <?if ($arItem["PERMISSION"] > "D"): // проверяем право доступа к пункту?>

   <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1): // если уровень вложенности =1, т.е. это главное меню?>
    <?// выводим ссылку и добавляем класс "root-item" если пункт неактивный и "root-item-selected" если активный?>
    <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>root-item-selected<?else:?>root-item<?endif?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?else: // для остальных уровней вложенности?>
    <?// выводим ссылку. Если пункт активный, для элемента списка <li> добавляем класс "item-selected"?>
    <li<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?> class="item-selected"<?endif?>><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?endif?>

  <?else: // для пунктов, к которым запрещен доступ?>

   <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1): // если уровень вложенности =1, т.е. это главное меню?>
    <?// выводим пустую ссылку и добавляем класс "root-item" если пункт неактивный и "root-item-selected" если активный?>
    <li><a href="" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>root-item-selected<?else:?>root-item<?endif?>" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?else: // для остальных уровней вложенности?>
    <?// выводим пустую ссылку и добавляем класс "denied"?>
    <li><a href="" class="denied" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?endif?>

  <?endif?>

 <?endif?>

 <?$previousLevel = $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]; // запоминаем уровень вложенности?>

<?endforeach?>

<?if ($previousLevel > 1):// если работа завершилась на пункте меню с уровнем вложенности >1, закрываем вложенные списки?>
 <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel-1) );?>
<?endif?>

</ul>
<div class="menu-clear-left"></div>
<?endif?>
```

Comment: задачу решил. Суть ошибки - неправильный шаблон был у меню. Отсюда ошибки были в лестничном меню.